# Flex widget load images from JSON, not all images displayed

Tags: json, image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, widget

I am trying to display the images in flex widget got from JSON. All works except the displaying of the images in the widget.

I have 12 pre-defined images in design mode of the widget, the source will be assigned at runtime when get the data from JSON. image1 to image4 for INFERIOR image, image5 to image 8 for NORMAL image, image9 to image12 for LUXURY image. (In fact, I intend to create image array at runtime, but failed to find a proper example.)

I use the same set of JSON data to test. The strange thing is every time the images displayed in the widget is different, for example, sometimes it displays all the images, sometimes it displays image2, image4, image7, sometimes it displays image1, image2, image5.

The source code I use:

```
private var value0:String;//id
private var value1:String;// type
private var value2:String;// image url

var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
request.url=getUrl;
request.requestHeaders=[new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")];
request.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;
var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receive);
loader.load(request);

protected function receive(event:Event):void
{
var myResults:Array= com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(event.target.data);

for (var i:int =0;i<myResults.length; i++){
  value0 = myResults[i].goods_id;
  value1 = myResults[i].goods_type;
  value2 = myResults[i].image_url;

  if (myResults[i].drawing_type == "INFERIOR"){
    if (!image1.source){
        image1.source = value2;
    }else if (!image2.source){
        image2.source = value2;
    }else if (!image3.source){
        image3.source = value2;
    }else if (!image4.source){
        image4.source = value2;
    }
  }

  if (myResults[i].drawing_type == "NORMAL"){
    if (!image5.source){
        image5.source = value2;
    }else if (!image6.source){
        image6.source = value2;
    }else if (!image7.source){
        image7.source = value2;
    }else if (!image8.source){
        image8.source = value2;
    }
  }

  if (myResults[i].drawing_type == "LUXURY"){
    if (!image9.source){
        image9.source = value2;
    }else if (!image10.source){
        image10.source = value2;
    }else if (!image11.source){
        image11.source = value2;
    }else if (!image12.source){
        image12.source = value2;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on this? Please advise me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the .source property is a little tricky. You can use flex `Loader` to load the image at runtime and assign it at the runtime. Doing this will allow you to find out what exceptions occured during runtime and error handling. Code below(see for Loader _)

http://ntt.cc/2008/03/09/tips-three-ways-to-load-an-image-file-in-flex.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Zens, I tried the 2nd and 3rd way, but result is the same.

Comment: @user30643 You may have to check if the image is located in the url you specified. copy the url and check it in the webbrowser and see if the image is lcoated

Comment: Thanks Zeus, yes I have already checked the url and image located.